# How to hide UITableView with Particular tableview.tag

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm creating a `UIScrollView` on top of that creating a `UITableView`

```
scrollViewForBP = [[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,225,balanceView.frame.size.width,balanceView.frame.size.height/2 - 30)];
scrollViewForBP.pagingEnabled = YES;
scrollViewForBP.contentSize =
CGSizeMake(CGRectGetWidth(scrollViewForBP.frame) * 3,scrollViewForBP.frame.size.height);
scrollViewForBP.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
scrollViewForBP.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
scrollViewForBP.directionalLockEnabled =YES;
scrollViewForBP.scrollsToTop = NO;
scrollViewForBP.delegate = self;
[balanceView addSubview:scrollViewForBP];


for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
{
    CGFloat xOrigin = i * scrollViewForBP.frame.size.width+10;

    Last5TransTblView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xOrigin,2,balanceView.frame.size.width-20,balanceView.frame.size.height/2 - 30) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    Last5TransTblView.tag= i;
    [Last5TransTblView setDelegate:self];
    [Last5TransTblView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone];
    [Last5TransTblView setDataSource:self];
    [Last5TransTblView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    Last5TransTblView.scrollEnabled = NO;
    Last5TransTblView.pagingEnabled = YES;
    [scrollViewForBP addSubview:Last5TransTblView];
}
```

Now I need to hide particular tab tableView. Any one please help me.

Comment: use if condition and check for tag. e.g, if(yourtableview.tag = 1)

Answer (score 0):

you can have any subview by using

```
[ParentView viewWithTag:15]
```

in your case you only need to use

```
[scrollViewForBP viewWithTag:desiredTag]
```

You can also type case it if you want to like this

```
UITableView *myTableView = (UITableView *)[scrollViewForBP viewWithTag:desiredTag];
```

After you have your tableView, you can hide it using **.hidden** , i.e

```
myTableView.hidden = YES
```

Comment: thanq Arslan for your quick reply. I'll check.